# JS - function take a double result

Tags: javascript, function, double

I got problem with this script:

```
<script>
var start = 400;
var interval = 40;

function counter() {
return start -= interval;
}

var stop = setInterval (
    function add() {
    if (counter() > 0)
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = counter();
    else
    clearInterval(stop);
    },1000);
</script>

<button onclick="clearInterval(stop)">stop!</button>
<br/>
        <p id="test">On marks! Start!</p>
```

The script counts down from 400 to 0, with a variable interval = 40. When the script runs it subtracts 80 instead of 40. The result is double and I don't know why.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling counter() twice, subtracting 40 each time, call it just once

```
var start = 400;
var interval = 40;

function counter() {
    return start -= interval;
}

var stop = setInterval(function() {
    var count = counter();
    if (count > 0) {
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = count;
    } else {
        clearInterval(stop);
    }
}, 1000);
```